# GHC seems to break Haskell 2010 layout rule

Tags: haskell, indentation, curly-braces

Think of the following code in Haskell:

```
f = y
  where { y = t where t = 2 }
```

Its intended meaning is

```
f = y
  where
    y = t
      where
        t = 2
```

and it **compiles as intended** with GHC 8.4.4. However it does not look like an appropriate behavior according to [Section 10.3 of Haskell 2010 Language Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3). Let me explain. The preprocess described there turns the above snippet to:

```
{1} f = y <3> where { y = t where {23} t = 2 }
```

Applying this to the function `L` in the Report yields parse-error at the last close-brace `}`! Explicitly, the symbol `{23}`, which is inserted since the second `where` is not followed by `{`, is interpreted as an implicit open-brace of level 23, and L reports parse-error for us closing this implicit open-brace with the explicit close-brace `}`!

I do hope I am making some mistake, but if I am not, is there any document on this conflict of behavior and specification?

Comment: Intuitively, in such case one should use the line `L (t : ts) (m : ms) = }  :  (L (t : ts) ms) if m /= 0 and parse-error(t)` to close the implicit brace, but I can't find any justification about why this equation should be applied at this point.